# vertx run -cp option doesn't work

Tags: vert.x

I have a question when I use `vertx run`.

My command is `vertx run groovy:myModule -conf conf.json`. But the dependencies are all in `lib`. I find the [doc](http://vertx.io/manual.html#running-verticles-directly) about add the classpath to vertx, just pass `-cp` to `vertx run`.

So I use `vertx run groovy:myModule -conf conf.json -cp "lib/*"`, but it doesn't works, also  throw `unable to resolve class` exception.

Then I read the vertx script, I find vertx will pass the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. So I try this way:

`CLASSPATH="lib/*" vertx run groovy:myModule -conf conf.json`

It works!

Why `-cp` is not work?

Comment: Did my answer below make sense or should I elaborate more?

Comment: @Kevin Bayes Thank you. I'm not online these days. So I reply a little late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the vertx script to add to the classpath you set the classpath property as you described above "CLASSPATH="lib/*".

This then gets used in the following line in the script:

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${VERTX_HOME}/conf:${VERTX_HOME}/lib/*
```

Then the last line of the script then uses this variable to set the java -classpath property when starting vertx:

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
"${JVM_OPTS[@]}" \
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${VERTX_JUL_CONFIG:-${VERTX_HOME}/conf/logging.properties} \
-Dvertx.home=$VERTX_HOME\
-Dvertx.clusterManagerFactory=org.vertx.java.spi.cluster.impl.hazelcast.HazelcastClusterManagerFactory\
-classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter "$@"
```

This is the reason setting the variable works and using -cp does not work. You could alter the script to accept a -cp input, but that would require you to customize the script.